# Working with GeometryCollection in Leaflet layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geometrycollection

I have a web app based on this template https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf
The app works fine with point geometry but I would like each feature to have a point and a polygon.

The geojson is:

> {   "type": "Feature",   "properties": {
>       "id": 1,
>       "Name": "Name",
>       "Reference": "123456789", "Address": "Street, Address",   },   "geometry": {
>       "type": "GeometryCollection",
>       "geometries": [
>         { "type": "Point",
>           "coordinates": [
>             -0.2340171,
>             51.4917468
>           ]  },
>         {
>           "type": "Polygon",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               [
>                 -0.2343982458114624,
>                 51.49143757352254
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.23387789726257327,
>                 51.491379122503375
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.233859121799469,
>                 51.49144091357853
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.23383498191833493,
>                 51.49144091357853
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.23364990949630737,
>                 51.49221913995003
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.23423194885253903,
>                 51.49227424989754
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.23440629243850708,
>                 51.491506044621154
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.2343848347663879,
>                 51.49150103454424
>               ],
>               [
>                 -0.2343982458114624,
>                 51.49143757352254
>               ]
>             ]
>           ]
>         }    ]   } }

The relevent part of the app:

```
var G1Layer = L.geoJson(null);
var G1s = L.geoJson(null, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                icon: 'fa-info',
                markerColor: 'red',
                shape: 'square',
                prefix: 'fa'
            }),

        title: feature.properties.S106,
        riseOnHover: true
    });
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
            var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Reference</th><td>" + feature.properties.reference + "</td></tr>" + "<table>";

            layer.on({
                click: function(e) {
                    $("#feature-title").html(feature.properties.S106);
                    $("#feature-info").html(content);
                    $("#featureModal").modal("show");
                    highlight.clearLayers().addLayer(L.circleMarker([feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]], highlightStyle));
                }
            });
            $("#feature-list tbody").append('<tr class="feature-row" id="' + L.stamp(layer) + '" lat="' + layer.getLatLng().lat + '" lng="' + layer.getLatLng().lng + '"><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-info" style="font-size:12px;color:red ;"></td><td class="feature-name">' + layer.feature.properties.name + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></td></tr>');
            G1Search.push({
                name: layer.feature.properties.name,
                address: layer.feature.properties.Address,
                source: "G1s",
                id: L.stamp(layer),
                lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
            });
        }
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    G1s.addData(G1Data);
   map.addLayer(G1Layer);
});
```

Comment: That GeoJSON [works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/BrrlmE42QqdvW2nZvoWq?p=preview). What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: I'm having a problem combining a marker and a polygon for the same feature or at the very least substituting markers in https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf with polygons. thanks